Be going to used in the past
I'd like to check if I know how the structure "be going to" works.

I am going to help when she arrives

As I understand 1 means it is my plan to help once she finally is with me. What about the past?

I was going to help her when she arrived

Does 2 have the same meaning as 1, it is just backshiftrd, or in the past it works differently and means that I was already in the middle of planning when she arrived or both are possible and it is just ambiguous? I'd like to ask about one more example,rather silly, yet possible.

You should have been going to do that when she came.

I have the same questions to my third and second example. Thanks.

It is backshifted to the past.  Just as "is going to" is used to talk about event in the future from now,  so "was going to" talks about events in the future from a past time.
It also suggests that the plans were not followed:

I was going to help her when she arrived, but had already finished the task so I didn't help her.

It gets that meaning simply because there would be no reason to talk about the future in the past if you had actually helped her.  You would just use the past tense instead.
As in most cases, there is no real difference in meaning between "going to" an "will".  "I was going to help her" and "I would have helped her" mean practically the same thing.
There's no actual error in your example 3, but such convoluted verb phrases are not normal.  I suspect you think that "going to" means "planning to". In fact it's just a way to talk about the future (including future plans)  But if you mean "planning" you should say so.  "You should have been planning to do that"

so my 2 and 3 examples mean that it was my plan to help her once she was with me after her arrival not that I was in the middle of planning when she came correct?

Yes, but your intent didn't bear fruit.

@Jamew K please check this examples "when she arrives I'm cooking" this either means that I am in the middle of cooking when she arrives or that when she arrives I will cook. What if I backshift my original sentence "when she arrived I was cooking". Does is it have two meanings too? Or it only means that I was in the middle of that action when she arrived?

That's a new question, in context I'd understand "I'm cooking" to be something that you intend to begin as soon as she arrives.  But this isn't an application of a grammar rule, I'm thinking about the situation that you present.

how do you understand my past version?

It suggests that the intent existed in the past but was not followed...   There that's the third time I've said it.

I mean this sentence 'I was cooking when she arrived". In my opinion it means that I was in the middle of cooking when she arrived. Is it also possible to interpret my sentence in this way that cooking happens after her arrival. I won't ask more questions here. Thank you in advance.

Please don't use the comments to ask new questions.  This question is about "was going to" construction
